# Android - Eprof tool

Tags: android, performance

I am interested in understanding the battery consumption of the android application i developed. I got to hear the term - "Eprof Tool" used for this purpose. But i dont find details on how to download the tool and steps for using the same.

If any pointers regarding this, please let me know.

Comment: Link where i found some info about eProf tool ... http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~pathaka/papers/2012-eurosys-pathak.pdf

Comment: I found a tool similar to EPROF named powertutor ... https://github.com/msg555/PowerTutor/downloads

Comment: hprof tool - To check the memory utilization, eprof - battery utilization ... gprof - cpu utilization. Hprof is available with android SDK ... But how to get the eprof and gprof tool ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a library which helps me compute the battery consumption of any application running either in foreground or background.

Also, E prof and g prof tools are not tools available in open market. Those tools were used by few researchers for their own project.

Thanks for all the support.

Answer (score 1):

If you see Abhinav Pathak in Likdin he is working as "IOS Power Engineer - Apple" and Ming Zhang is 8 years researcher in Microsoft.
After paper "keeping my phone wake" i have the impression they are developing for iOs too.

The best alternative i have found is AppScope:
https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/yoon_atc12_slides.pdf
If you see slide 26 they do the same thing in "eprof fine grained energy".
You can also check slide 29... PowerTutor seems also a good choose.

AppScope Package
http://css3.yonsei.ac.kr:5612/appscope/wiki/Downloads

See also...
ANEPROF: Energy Profiling for Android Java Virtual Machine and Applications